# Find the area between $x = y + \sin(y)$ and $ x = 2 - y^2$

Tags: calculus

A really simple question here.

> $$x = y + \sin(y)$$ and $$ x = 2 - y^2$$

I’m having trouble finding the area between these curves and figuring out how to accurately locate the intersection points using a graphing calculator.

Comment: It may depend on what are we used to, but here I{d interchange $\;x\;$ with $\;y\;$ and look all as $\;y\;$ functions of $\;x\;$ .

Comment: Hint: change the roles of $x$ and $y$, the area is the same and the problem looks more familiar.

Comment: Anyway, to solve this you must solve a transcendental equation: $\;x^2+x-2+\sin x=0\;$ . This doesn't look nice at all...perhaps with some approximations. I really can't say

Comment: Thanks to all! It has cleared things up to change y and x.

Comment: @Ivan Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

We need to show by calculus that $f(y)=y^2+y+\sin y-2$ has exactly $2$ roots and [**solve numerically**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Bsinx%3D2-x%5E2) the equation

$$y^2+y+\sin y-2=0$$

to obtain $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $f(y_1)=f(y_2)=0$ and then evaluate

$$A=\left|\int_{y_1}^{y_2} (2-y^2) - (y+\sin y) \,dy\right|=\left|\left[2y-\frac {y^3} 3-\frac{y^2}2+\cos y\right]_{y_1}^{y_2}\right|$$